# Android custom ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Is it possible to create a `custom ContentProvider` to

- Access android existing database (e.g. Contacts, SMS)?
- Extend an Exciting ContentProvider which has access to android existing database (e.g. ContactsProvider to access Contacts DB)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes

Longer answer:

`ContentProviders` are a layer sitting in between the "outside world" (e.g. other Android `Activities`) and the back-end data storage. You will never have *direct* access to the database. The database is stored in the `Activities` private storage space. So all you can do is dictated by the `ContentProvider` you are addressing.

If the `ContentProvider` only allows read-only access to the data, than that is all you can do.

So in the end, you can only offer access which has at **most** the kind of access as the `ContentProvider` you are using. You can however expose a different data structure. Or you could also create one `ContentProvider` which uses multiple other providers internally.

On the bottom line, within the given bounds, your imagination is the limit.